# Library Startup Skript in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

Using Dymola, I'm looking for a way to automatically execute a script when loading a library. The intention is to define additional `displayUnits` using the `defineUnitConversion()` command, which are specific to the library that is loaded. Still I think there are quite some other cases where this could be helpful.

What I figured out in this regard:

- I know that it is possible to add conversions to the file in `DymolaInstallDir/insert/displayUnits.mos` but this comes with the disadvantage that is has to be done again on every new computer or after an update of Dymola. I would like to avoid this.
- Other than that I only found the `libraryinfo.mos` file, which seems to be read during the start-up of Dymola. Therefore I assume it is not the right place to put the conversions, as it contains general information about the library and should only contain the respective functions.

Comment: If you open Dymola and then look at command window, you should be able to see which scripts have been executed during startup. In my case, I only see `RunScript("c:/program files/dymola 2020/insert/dymola.mos", true);` so it should be possible to call any other script from that dymola.mos script.

Comment: Hey matth, thanks for the comment! I guess this would work, but it is non-portable solution. I would like to have the script executed on any machine when loading the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dymola 2022 has a new (tool-specific) feature that covers exactly this use-case. It is mentioned in the [Dymola 2022 release notes](https://www.3ds.com/fileadmin/PRODUCTS/CATIA/DYMOLA/PDF/Dymola-2022-release-notes.pdf) in the section "Library startup script" on page 24.

It basically introduces the a new annotation, which allows to specify a path to a `.mos` script, which is executed, when the respective library is loaded. Here is the example from the release notes:

```
package ThisPack
 annotation(__Dymola_startup =
 "modelica://ThisPack/Resources/Scripts/Dymola/startup.mos");
end ThisPack;
```

The annotation can also be set via the UI...