Dymola startup modification with dymola.mos
I want to modify the working directory during startup of Dymola.
I have come across this article from Claytex about a file called dymola.mos, that is loaded during the startup of Dymola. I have already used this to modify some variables (works), however, I'm unsure how to change the working directory. Here's the code (first block is the default content of the file, 3rd block is the working modification of the variables):
// RunScript("$DYMOLA/insert/displayunit.mos", true);
// RunScript("$DYMOLA/insert/displayunit_us.mos", true);
definePostProcessing("SDF output", "Convert result file to SDF format", "Modelica.Utilities.System.command(\"\\\"%DYMOLA%/bin/dsres2sdf\\\" %RESULTFILE%.mat %RESULTFILE%.sdf\")");


// Working directory
cd("C:/Data/Dymola");

// Settings
Advanced.Translation.MaxStringLength = 5000;
Advanced.Translation.ParallelizeCode = true;

Can somebody help with this? Also, is there a more extensive description / tutorial of what can be done with this script?

Well, the line cd("C:/Data/Dymola"); seems alright to me. Did you have an issue with it?

Ok, thanks for confirming. Something was going wrong on my system, however, it now works as expected. Thanks =)

I am just trying this again on another computer and it is not working. This is very curious.
Edit: Just found the reason. On this particular PC, in "Tools -> Options -> Settings", I had "Save last working directory" ticked. It seems that Dymola enforces that setting AFTER running the dymola.mos script. "C:/Data/Dymola" actually showed up in the "Files -> Working Directory" menu, so I knew this must have been added because the script actually worked

I mostly work with projet scripts, which are launched AFTER the Dymola.mos. This way, I can easily change my working directory related to the project, and open the corresponding packages.

I recommend to also take a look at this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719451/library-startup-skript-in-dymola?rq=2

As indicated in the comment "Tools -> Options -> Settings",
"Save last working directory" is applied after running start-up script, thus overriding the cd-command in the start-up script.
Apart from that it is just a normal script.
